# "Universal property" of cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, cross-product, universal-property

Let $V$ be a three dimensional euclidian vector space which is oriented. Because of the orientation, we can define the cross product $\times: V^2 \rightarrow V$ uniquely by: $<v\times w,u> = \det(v,w,u)$. Now suppose we have another real vector space $W$ and let $c:V^2\rightarrow W$ be an alternating bilinear form. Intuitively, $\times$ should have some kind of universal property, namely that we get a unique $\phi_c:V\rightarrow W$, such that $\phi_c(\times) = c$.

Intuitively this makes sense, but how would one go of proving this? I'm struggling to see which notable parts of $c$ to use to construct $\phi$. Note that this is part of an assignment, so hints rather than solutions would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\det(v,w,u)$ here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another universal property that is related and much more well known, which is the universal property of the [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra). In particular, there is a universal property for each $\Lambda^k(V)$, and the one we need is the following:

**Universal Property of the Exterior Product**: Let $V$ be a vector space. Given any alternating bilinear map $\mu: V\times V\rightarrow W$, there exists a uniquely induced linear map $\tilde{\mu}:\Lambda^2(V)\rightarrow W$ such that $\tilde{\mu}\circ\wedge = \mu$, where $\wedge:V\times V \rightarrow \Lambda^2(V)$ is the exterior product map.

The exterior product is intimately related to the cross product. You should be able to translate this universal property into the one that you need.