# antisymmetric bilinear map and cross product

Tags: differential-forms, cross-product

Given an antisymmetric bilinear map, $g:\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow V$, where $V$ is a vector space, is it true that there is a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow V$ such that $g(u,v) = f(u\times v)\ \forall\ u,v\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $\times$ being the cross product?

There is a result that resembles this in Harley Flanders' Differential Forms book on page 7 for $p$-forms, but without proof.

Comment: This is true. The point is that cross products gives a bijective linear map from the set of skew-symmetric tensors of rank two and ordinary vectors.

Comment: Blazej, thank you, could you please elaborate a bit, perhaps give some pointers toward a proof?

Comment: This is closely related to but not quite a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845423/universal-property-of-cross-product?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The universal property guarantees that any bilinear map $$h : \Bbb R^3 \times \Bbb R^3 \to V$$ factors through a linear map $$h' : \Bbb R^3 \otimes \Bbb R^3 \to V ,$$ so that $h({\bf x}, {\bf y}) = h'({\bf x} \otimes {\bf y})$.

If $h$ is alternating, then $h'({\bf x} \otimes {\bf x}) = h({\bf x}, {\bf x}) = {\bf 0}$ for all ${\bf x} \in \Bbb R^3$, so $h'$ descends to a map $\tilde h : (\Bbb R^3 \otimes \Bbb R^3) / I \to V$, where $I$ is the subspace spanned by the tensors ${\bf x} \otimes {\bf x}$, ${\bf x} \in \Bbb R^3$, but by definition we can identify $(\Bbb R^3 \otimes \Bbb R^3) / I$ with $\bigwedge^2 \Bbb R^3$ and so regard $\tilde h$ as a map $$\tilde h : {\bigwedge}^2 \, \Bbb R^3 \to V .$$

Now, consider the special case where $V = \Bbb R^3$ and $h$ is the cross product map $C: \Bbb R^3 \otimes \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$. Here, the map $\tilde C$ is an isomorphism: For an oriented, orthonormal basis $(E_a)$ of $\Bbb R^3$ we have (up to an overall positive constant that depends on convention) that $\tilde C(E_2 \wedge E_3) = E_1$ and its cyclic permutations. Unwinding definitions, we have $$g = \tilde g \circ \tilde C^{-1} \circ C ,$$ or equivalently that $$g(u, v) = (\tilde g \circ \tilde C^{-1}) (u \times v) .$$

[image]

---

We can make this more concrete: If we write $u = \sum_{i = 1}^3 u_i E_i$ and $v = \sum_{i = 1}^3 v_i E_i$ we have (using antisymmetry of $h$) that
$$h(u, v) = (u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2) h(E_2, E_3) + (\textrm{cyclic permutations}) .$$ But we recognize the coefficients from the usual formula
$$u \times v = (u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2) E_1 + (\textrm{cyclic permutations}),$$
so the desired map $f : \Bbb R^3 \to V$ satisfying $g(u, v) = f(u \times v)$ is characterized by
$$f(E_1) = h(E_2, E_3)$$
and its cyclic permutations.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the link to the universal property in exterior algebra, and for providing a concrete proof

Comment: pretty  n i c e...